# Script to generate graphical log in Sheets has error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a Script that generates logs of soil in Sheets.

Essentially, You run BoreLog>Create Borelog from the menu and it grabs information from any tabes with "Bore " prefix, and generates a Log of Bore bore log.

At the moment there is a new error "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.

I cannot work out where the issue is being generated from/the cause.

Can any one help?

### Link to sheet with error: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZApQBSziIxepXc3hrQeTliyJpS_3jk7KNdMJu7BHHQY/edit?usp=sharing
Script is below:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("BoreLog").addItem("Create Borelog", "createBorelog").addToUi();
}

function createBorelog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sh;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getName().indexOf('Log of') == 0) {
      sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName());
      ss.deleteSheet(sh);
    }
  }
  
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  //Logger.log(sheets);
  var name = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    
    if (sheets[i].getName().indexOf('Bore') == 0) {
      //Logger.log(i);
      Logger.log(sheets[i].getName());
      populateWell(sheets[i].getName());
      createLogs(sheets[i].getName());
    }
  }
  return;
}

function createLogs(shName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  sht.showSheet();
  var shName;
  sht.copyTo(ss);
  
  var shTemplate = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Template').setName('Log of ' + shName).setTabColor("red");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(shName);
  var shdata = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = {};
  var drilling = {};
  var wellPipe = {};
  var boreConstruct = {};
  var drillRow, wellRow, boreRow, i;
  var max = 0;
  var HeaderValues = [];
  var FooterValues = [];
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[0][3], shdata[2][6], shdata[2][13]]); //1
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[1][2], shdata[0][13], shdata[2][2]]); //2
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[0][9], shdata[1][13], shdata[3][2]]); //3
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[1][9], shdata[2][9], shdata[1][17]]); //4
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[0][6], shdata[3][9], shdata[2][17]]); //5
  HeaderValues.push([shdata[1][6], shdata[0][17], shdata[3][17]]); //6
  FooterValues.push([shdata[3][4], shdata[3][6], "Checked By", shdata[3][13]]);
  FooterValues.push(["This Borelog Template is under Copyright of iEnvironmental Australia Pty Ltd 2022."]);
  FooterValues.push(["Disclaimer: This bore log is intended for environmental and not geotechnical purposes."]);
  FooterValues.push(["mbgs = metres below ground surface. Moisture Description: D=dry, SM=slightly moist, M=moist, VM=very moist, W=wet/saturated"]);
  for (i = 0; i < shdata.length; i++) {
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "drilling method")
      drillRow = i;
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "well pipe construction")
      wellRow = i;
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "bore construction")
      boreRow = i;
  }

  Logger.log('Drill row = ' + drillRow + ' Well row = ' + wellRow + ' Bore row = ' + boreRow)
  
  for (i = drillRow + 1; i < shdata.length; i++) {
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "select" || shdata[i][0] == '')
      break;
    drilling[shdata[i][0]] = {};
    drilling[shdata[i][0]].upper = shdata[i][1];
    drilling[shdata[i][0]].lower = shdata[i][2];
    if (shdata[i][2] > max)
      max = shdata[i][2];
    
  }
  
  for (i = wellRow + 1; i < shdata.length; i++) {
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "select" || shdata[i][0] == '')
      break;
    wellPipe[shdata[i][0]] = {}
    wellPipe[shdata[i][0]].upper = shdata[i][1];
    wellPipe[shdata[i][0]].lower = shdata[i][2];
    if (shdata[i][2] > max)
      max = shdata[i][2];
  }
  
  for (i = boreRow + 1; i < shdata.length; i++) {
    if (shdata[i][0].toLowerCase() == "select" || shdata[i][0] == '')
      break;
    
    boreConstruct[shdata[i][0]] = {}
    boreConstruct[shdata[i][0]].upper = shdata[i][1];
    boreConstruct[shdata[i][0]].lower = shdata[i][2];
    if (shdata[i][2] > max)
      max = shdata[i][2];
  }
  var bores = Object.keys(boreConstruct);
  var wells = Object.keys(wellPipe);
  if(boreConstruct[bores[bores.length-1]].lower > wellPipe[wells[wells.length-1]].lower) {
    wellPipe[bores[bores.length-1]] = {};
    wellPipe[bores[bores.length-1]].upper = wellPipe[wells[wells.length-1]].lower;
    wellPipe[bores[bores.length-1]].lower = boreConstruct[bores[bores.length-1]].lower;
  }
  for (i = 6; i < shdata.length; i++) {
    if (shdata[i][STARTP - 1] == '' && i > 7)
      break;
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]] = {}
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].uscs = shdata[i][USCS - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].startp = shdata[i][STARTP - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].endp = shdata[i][ENDP - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].mdesc = shdata[i][DESC - 1] + " (" + (shdata[i][STARTP - 1] || '0') + " to " + (shdata[i][ENDP - 1] || '0') + " mbgs)";
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].moist = shdata[i][MOIST - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].odour = shdata[i][ODOUR - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].pid = shdata[i][PID - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].sample = shdata[i][SAMPLES - 1];
    data[shdata[i][STYPE - 1]].analysed = shdata[i][ANALYSED - 1];
    if (shdata[i][2] > max)
      max = shdata[i][ENDP - 1];
  }
  
  var other = {}
  if (typeof shdata[2][2] == 'number')
    other.waterEnc = shdata[2][2];
  if (typeof shdata[3][2] == 'number')
    other.waterSta = shdata[3][2];
  var temp = shdata[3][9].toString().split('/');
  other.smahd = parseFloat(temp[0]);
  
  var graphics = {};
  graphics.depths = data;
  graphics.drill = drilling;
  graphics.pipe = wellPipe;
  graphics.bore = boreConstruct;
  graphics.maxValue = max;
  graphics.other = other;
  graphics.HeaderValues = HeaderValues;
  graphics.FooterValues = FooterValues;
  setDepth(graphics, shTemplate);
  sht.hideSheet();
  return;
}

function setDepth(graphics, shTemplate) {
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 1, shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn() + 1).clearFormat().clearContent();
  var HeaderValues = graphics.HeaderValues;
  var FooterValues = graphics.FooterValues;
  setHeader(HeaderValues, shTemplate);
  var depths = graphics.depths, drill = graphics.drill, pipe = graphics.pipe, bore = graphics.bore,
      max = graphics.maxValue;
  var other = graphics.other;
  var smahd = other.smahd;
  var waterEncLevel = other.waterEnc;
  var waterStaLevel = other.waterSta;
  var keys = Object.keys(depths);
  var i = Math.floor(depths[keys[1]].startp);
  var temp = Math.ceil(max);
  var j = temp * 100;
  var mdesc, sample, odour, moist, pid, startp, endp, uscs, analysed;
  var rowsValue = [0], erowsValue = [], eno, mergeThisRows = {}, mergeThisRowsE = {}, rowSN = 1, rowEN, rowsN, k;
  while (i <= j) {
    rowsValue.push(i / 100);
    eno = parseFloat(smahd - (i / 100)).toFixed(2);
    if (eno != undefined) {
      erowsValue.push(eno);
    }
    i = i + 10;
  }
  
  for (var i = 1; i < rowsValue.length; i++) {
    if (i != 1) {
      if (rowsValue[i] % 1 == 0 && i !== rowsValue.length - 1) {
        mergeThisRows[rowsValue[i]] = i + 1;
        if (erowsValue[i] != undefined)
          mergeThisRowsE[Math.round(erowsValue[i] * 100) / 100] = i + 1;
      }
    }
    if (rowsValue[i] == (Math.round(waterStaLevel * 10) / 10))
    var x = i;
    if (rowsValue[i] == (Math.round(waterEncLevel * 10) / 10))
    var y = i;
    shTemplate.getRange(i + STARTT_ROW - 1, DEPTH_COL, 1, 1).setBorder(true, true, true, false, false, false).setFontSize(6).setValue(rowsValue[i]).setFontColor("white");
    shTemplate.getRange(i + STARTT_ROW, ELEVATION_COL, 1, 1).setBorder(true, true, true, false, false, false).setFontSize(6).setValue(rowsValue[i]).setFontColor("white");
    shTemplate.setRowHeight(i + STARTT_ROW, size);
    
  }
  var rKeys = Object.keys(mergeThisRows);
  var eKeys = Object.keys(mergeThisRowsE);
  for (k = 0; k < rKeys.length; k++) {
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, DEPTH_COL + 1, 2, 1).breakApart().merge().setValue(rKeys[k]).setFontColor("black").setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, DEPTH_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);;
    if (eKeys[k] != undefined) {
      shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRowsE[eKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, ELEVATION_COL + 1, 2, 1).breakApart().merge().setValue(eKeys[k]-(-0.1)).setNumberFormat("0.0").setFontColor("black").setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
      shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRowsE[eKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW - 1, ELEVATION_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    }
  }
  
  //return;

  shTemplate.getRange("a8:r8").setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID).setBackground('#efefef');
  //shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 2).setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);//try setting border of surface
  //shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 4).setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);//try setting border of surface
  //shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 12).setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);//try setting border of surface
  //return;

  setBorders(mergeThisRows, shTemplate, x, y, rowsValue.lastIndexOf(max) + STARTT_ROW);

  //return;
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 12).setBorder(true, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

  var flag = false, temp3 = 0, flag1 = false;
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, MDESC_COL).setValue(depths[keys[0]].mdesc).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP).setFontSize(fsize).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);

  //return;

  for (var i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
    startp = Math.ceil(depths[keys[i]].startp * 10);
    if (depths[keys[i]].endp != '')
      endp = Math.ceil(depths[keys[i]].endp * 10);
    else
      endp = Math.ceil(max * 10);
    uscs = depths[keys[i]].uscs;
    sample = depths[keys[i]].sample;
    odour = depths[keys[i]].odour;
    pid = depths[keys[i]].pid;
    mdesc = depths[keys[i]].mdesc;
    moist = depths[keys[i]].moist;
    analysed = depths[keys[i]].analysed;
    rowSN = rowsValue.lastIndexOf(startp / 10);
    rowEN = rowsValue.lastIndexOf(endp / 10);
    if (rowEN === 0) {
      rowEN = rowsValue.length;
    }
    rowsN = rowEN - rowSN;
    if (rowsN === 0) {
      rowsN = 1;
    }
    
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, GRAPHICS_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setBorder(true, false, true, false, false, false);
    
    var c = shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, GRAPHICS_COL, rowsN, 1).getA1Notation();
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, USCS_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(uscs).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setFontWeight("bold").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, SAMPLES_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(sample).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontWeight("bold").setFontSize(6).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, ANALYSED_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(analysed).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontWeight("bold").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
    if (rowsN > 1)
      shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, MDESC_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(mdesc).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP).setWrap(true).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
    else
      shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, MDESC_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(mdesc).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, MOISTURE_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(moist).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, ODOUR_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(odour).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("left").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
    shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, PID_COL, rowsN, 1).merge().setValue(pid).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP);
    
    
    for (var j = 0; j < IKEYS.length; j++) {
      if (IKEYS[j].toString().toLowerCase() == uscs.toLowerCase()) {
        while (rowSN != rowEN) {
          shTemplate.getRange(rowSN + STARTT_ROW, GRAPHICS_COL).setFormula('=IMAGE("' + IMAGES[IKEYS[j]] + '",2)').setVerticalAlignment('top').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
          rowSN++
            
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
  //return;
  setDrill(rowsValue, drill, shTemplate, mergeThisRows);
  setBore(rowsValue, bore, shTemplate, mergeThisRows);
  //return;
  setWell(rowsValue, pipe, shTemplate, mergeThisRows);
  setFooter(FooterValues, shTemplate);
  shTemplate.getRange(rowsValue.lastIndexOf(max) + STARTT_ROW, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, true, null, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  //return;
}

function setDrill(rows, drill, shTemplate, mergeThisRows) {
  var keys = Object.keys(drill);
  var i, j, startp, endp, diff, row;
  
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    startp = drill[keys[i]].upper * 10;
    endp = drill[keys[i]].lower * 10;
    if (endp == 0)
      break;
    var startRow = rows.lastIndexOf(startp / 10);
    var endRow = rows.lastIndexOf(endp / 10);
    if (endRow === 0) {
      endRow = rows.length;
    }
    diff = endRow - startRow;
    if (diff === 0)
      diff = 1;
    shTemplate.getRange(startRow + STARTT_ROW, DRILLING_COL, diff, 1).breakApart();
    
    shTemplate.getRange(startRow + STARTT_ROW, DRILLING_COL, diff, 1).merge().setValue(keys[i]).setFontWeight("bold").setFontSize(fsize).setHorizontalAlignment("center").setVerticalAlignment("middle").setWrap(true).setBorder(true, true, false, true, false, false);
    
  }
  return;
}

function setWell(rows, pipe, shTemplate, mergeThisRows) {
  var keys = Object.keys(pipe);
  var i, j, startp, endp, diff, row;
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, WELL_COL, rows.length, 1).breakApart();
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof pipe[keys[i]].upper != 'number')
      break;
    startp = pipe[keys[i]].upper * 10;
    endp = pipe[keys[i]].lower * 10;
    var row = rows.lastIndexOf(startp / 10);
    var endRow = rows.lastIndexOf(endp / 10);
    if (endRow === 0) {
      endRow = rows.length;
    }
    diff = endRow - row;
    if (diff === 0)
      diff = 1;
    
    shTemplate.getRange(row + STARTT_ROW, WELL_COL, diff, 1).breakApart().merge().setFormula('=IMAGE("' + IMAGES[keys[i]] + '",2)').setVerticalAlignment("middle").setBorder(true, true, null, true, null, null).setFontSize(fsize);
  }
  return;
}

function setBore(rows, bore, shTemplate, mergeThisRows) {
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW + 1, BORE1_COL, rows.length, 1).breakApart();
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW + 1, BORE2_COL, rows.length, 1).breakApart();
  //  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW + 1, WELL_COL, rows.length, 1).breakApart();
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW + 1, BORENAME_COL, rows.length, 1).breakApart();
  var keys = Object.keys(bore);
  var i, j, startp, endp, diff, row;
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof bore[keys[i]].upper != 'number')
      break;
    startp = bore[keys[i]].upper * 10;
    endp = bore[keys[i]].lower * 10;
    var row = rows.lastIndexOf(startp / 10);
    var endRow = rows.lastIndexOf(endp / 10);
    if (endRow === 0) {
      endRow = rows.length;
    }
    diff = endRow - row;
    if (diff === 0)
      diff = 1;
    shTemplate.getRange(row + STARTT_ROW, BORE1_COL, diff, 1).breakApart().merge().setFormula('=IMAGE("' + IMAGES[keys[i]] + '",2)').setVerticalAlignment('top').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setFontSize(fsize);
    shTemplate.getRange(row + STARTT_ROW, BORE2_COL, diff, 1).breakApart().merge().setFormula('=IMAGE("' + IMAGES[keys[i]] + '",2)').setVerticalAlignment('top').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setFontSize(fsize);
  //    shTemplate.getRange(row + STARTT_ROW, WELL_COL, diff, 1).breakApart().merge().setFormula('=IMAGE("' + IMAGES[keys[i]] + '",2)').setVerticalAlignment('top').setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false).setFontSize(fsize);
    shTemplate.getRange(row + STARTT_ROW, BORENAME_COL, diff, 1).breakApart().merge().setValue(keys[i]).setFontWeight("bold").setFontSize(fsize).setVerticalAlignment("middle").setHorizontalAlignment("center").setWrap(true).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
  }
  return;
}

function setBorders(mergeThisRows, shTemplate, x, y, max) {
  ///GET HEIGHTS AND WIDTHS
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 5, shTemplate.getLastRow() - 7, shTemplate.getLastColumn() - 4).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, false)
  var rKeys = Object.keys(mergeThisRows);
  for (var k = 0; k < rKeys.length; k++) {
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW, DEPTH_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    shTemplate.getRange(mergeThisRows[rKeys[k]] + STARTT_ROW, ELEVATION_COL + 1, 2, 1).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  }
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false)
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW, 5, shTemplate.getLastRow() - 7, shTemplate.getLastColumn() - 4).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, false)
  if (x == y && x != undefined) {
    shTemplate.getRange(x + STARTT_ROW - 1, WATER_COL, 1, 1).setValue(WATERICONSTA).setBorder(false, true, true, true, false, false).setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  } else if (x != y) {
    if (x != undefined)
      shTemplate.getRange(x + STARTT_ROW - 1, WATER_COL, 1, 1).setValue(WATERICONSTA).setBorder(null, true, true, true, null, null).setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    if (y != undefined)
      shTemplate.getRange(y + STARTT_ROW - 1, WATER_COL, 1, 1).setValue(WATERICONENC).setBorder(null, true, true, true, null, null).setFontSize(6).setVerticalAlignment("top").setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  }
  shTemplate.getRange(STARTT_ROW - 1, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  shTemplate.getRange(max, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, true, null, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  return;
}

function setHeader(HeaderValues, shTemplate) {
  shTemplate.getRange(1, 8).setValue(HeaderValues[0][0])
  shTemplate.getRange(1, 13).setValue(HeaderValues[0][1])
  shTemplate.getRange(1, 18).setValue(HeaderValues[0][2]) //notes
  
  for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    shTemplate.getRange(i, 8).setValue(HeaderValues[i - 1][0]);
    shTemplate.getRange(i, 13).setValue(HeaderValues[i - 1][1]);
    shTemplate.getRange(i, 18).setValue(HeaderValues[i - 1][2]);
  }
}

function setFooter(FooterValues, shTemplate) {
  var b = shTemplate.getName();
  var c = shTemplate.getLastColumn()
  
  var a = shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, shTemplate.getLastColumn()).setBorder(true, false, false, false, false, false);
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, 3).merge().setValue(FooterValues[0][0]).setBackground("#54c230").setFontColor("white").setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6);
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow(), 5, 1, 3).merge().setValue(FooterValues[0][1]).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6);
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow(), 8, 1, 2).merge().setValue(FooterValues[0][2]).setBackground("#54c230").setFontColor("white").setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6);
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow(), 10).setValue(FooterValues[0][3]).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6);
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 2).setValue(FooterValues[3][0]).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6).setFontWeight("bold");
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 2).setValue(FooterValues[2][0]).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6).setFontWeight("bold");
  shTemplate.getRange(shTemplate.getLastRow() + 1, 2).setValue(FooterValues[1][0]).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(6).setFontWeight("bold");
} 

function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index");
}

function getLoc(value) {
  var destId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId() ;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destId) ;
  var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0] ;
  var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues() ;
  var headers = data[0] ;
  var numColumns = headers.length ;
  var numResponses = data.length;
  var c=value[0]; var d=value[1];
  var e=c + "," + d ;
   if (respSheet.getRange(1, numColumns).getValue()=="GeoAddress") {    
       respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
       respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns-1).setValue(e);
       var response = Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(value[0], value[1]);
       f= response.results[0].formatted_address;
       respSheet.getRange(numResponses,numColumns).setValue(f);
     }
   else if (respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns).getValue()!="GeoAddress") {
       respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+1).setValue("GeoStamp");
       respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+2).setValue("GeoCode");
       respSheet.getRange(1,numColumns+3).setValue("GeoAddress");
  }
}

function populateWell(shName){
  Logger.log(shName);
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shName);
  if(sh.getRange('A11').isBlank()){
    sh.getRange('A11').setValue('-');
  }
  if(sh.getRange('A16').isBlank()){
    sh.getRange('A16').setValue('-');
  }
  //Logger.log(checkRange);
}
```

Comment: The error log should tell you the function and line number where the error occurs.